# How to make changes in one Google Sheet column auto update other columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Example Google Sheet** - [Grocery Store](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tw5EGObQFcqk_cyTMYV3xFaP81XZniBcp4ZSRw2O_ag/edit?usp=sharing).

On the sheet 'Stock' there are the items for sale (column Name) and the quantity for each item (column Quantity).

On the sheet 'Sales' the name of the item sold will be selected from a dropdown list and the number of items sold should be entered manually.

**What needs to be done:**

Create a Google Sheets function `=SELL(n)`, where n = number of items sold. The function should have the following properties:

a) `checkName` - check the cell to the left for the item name and find in in 'Stock' tab, for example 'Apples'

b) `decreaseQty` - Decrease Quantity in 'Stock' by the number of items sold. For example, if we had 10 Apples in Stock and sold 1, there should be 9 left.

b) `increaseSold` - Increase Sold items in 'Stock' by the number of items sold. For example, if we had 5 Apples sold and sold 1 more, there should be 6.

c) (Optional step). Nr. of items sold greater than Quantity in 'Stock' should not be allowed.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot that these foods are perishable so in a week they will probably all go bad anyway. You do not need a script or macro, you should never use a script or macro unless you absolutely cannot do it from within google sheets with regular formulas.

Comment: If you are looking for a code rather than cell formulas, you should make some attempt to write a code yourself and people will happily help you where you got stuck. As for the general workflow - either with script or cell formulas - it will be easier if you implement auxiliary columns: A column for the initial quantity - e.g. 10; a dynamic column for total sold items  -e.g. 1; and a third column that looks like your column B: 10-1. To create the third column you need to stringify the values, e.g. with the cell formula '=CONCATENATE(D2,"-",E2)'.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your data currently set up is not optimal for what you are trying to do, instead you should have a list of transactions, the first being beginning balance and then use negative numbers to represent sold. Your inventory should be calculated from your list of transactions.

For example you will make your list of transactions look like this:

```
Apples  10
Oranges 14
Tomatoes    21
Potatoes    47
Apples  -1
Oranges -5
Potatoes    -2
```

Comment: This would accomplish the task but unfortunately I'm dealing with a legacy system, so it should work exactly as described in my initial question.

Comment: @DorinD There is not enough detail to work as described, nothing is working, because how are you going to set the inventory? You are only showing me two things, an `output` screen that you apparently expect the user to just write over magically and a sale screen to enter only sales, what about perished items, what about lost items, what about mistake entries, you can only subtract but you can't add? So then what happens once everything is gone, problem solved legacy system self destructed. There is probably more details, but from what I can see it's error prone with no way to correct.

Comment: You don't need to worry about how the system is or should be. There is a specific task which should be solved in a specific way. Period. Further improvements, additions and error checking I will add myself, if necessary. Consider this a school project, which is neither perfect, nor exhaustive and meant only for educational purposes.

Comment: @DorinD I can't answer the question without worrying how it should be because any answer I give is going to involve adding extra columns or cells, is this ok? Your original question says you want `Create a function =SELL(n), where n = number of items sold. The function should have the following methods:` what does it mean for a function to have methods???

Comment: This is a fair observation. Please consider we are talking about a Google Sheets function, which is different from a Java function. Inside this GS function we can have other functions. I renamed them as ”properties”, just to have a difference between GS function and all subsequent functions.

Comment: @DorinD oh I see I totally did not understand what you meant, your question seems very vague and not a very specific problem, don't you agree? I think you should be posting your current function with properties and state what is wrong with it so that we can help you correct it.